# d3 - Rotate x-axis labels

Tags: javascript, d3.js, heatmap, timeline

I'm trying this [**graph**](http://bl.ocks.org/tjdecke/5558084):

[image]

with my data.

I wanted to rotate the `x-axis` labels.

Here's the code :

```
var timeLabels = svg.selectAll(".timeLabel")
          .data(times)
          .enter().append("text")
            .text(function(d) { return d; })
            .attr("x", function(d, i) { return i * gridSize; })
            .attr("y", 0)
            .style("text-anchor", "end")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + gridSize / 2 + ", -6)rotate(-90)")
            .attr("class", function(d, i) { return ((i >= 8 && i <= 16) ? "timeLabel mono axis axis-worktime" : "timeLabel mono axis"); });
```

But the result I get is. Entire labels get rotated to -90 deg in a single straight line. Instead I wanted each label to be rotated to -90 deg. Like [**this**](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4403522):

[image]

I even tried using `.attr("transform", function(d) {return "translate(" + gridSize / 2 + ", -6)rotate(-90)"})` but it didn't help.

Result :

[image]

Help will be very much pleased.

Comment: Have you seen [this tutorial](http://www.d3noob.org/2013/01/how-to-rotate-text-labels-for-x-axis-of.html)?

Comment: Yea i tried but the result is not what i expected. I'll post the image.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that when you rotate an element, it gets rotated around the origin point, (0,0), of the local coordinate system.  If the element you're rotating isn't right next to the origin, it can end up moved quite a large distance, and possibly moved outside the chart altogether.

There are two ways you can fix it:

1. Position the label with a "transform" attribute instead of with x and y attributes.  That way, the label's coordinate system -- including the (0,0) point of rotation -- will be positioned with it, and the rotation will happen where you expect.  The code @Manoj gave follows that system, but assumes you are using the default xAxis function.  For your custom axis label code, your labels are given a `y` value of 0, and an `x` value determined from a function.  You just need to move those values into the `transform` attribute, paying careful attention that the transformation of the overall position comes *before* the rotation and adjustment:

   ```
   var timeLabels = svg.selectAll(".timeLabel")
     .data(times)
     .enter().append("text")
       .text(function(d) { return d; })
       .attr("transform", function(d, i) { 
             return "translate(" + ( i * gridSize) + ",0)"
                     + "translate(" + gridSize / 2 + ", -6)rotate(-90)";
        } )
       .style("text-anchor", "end")
       .attr("class", function(d, i) { return ((i >= 8 && i <= 16) ? 
                                  "timeLabel mono axis axis-worktime" : 
                                  "timeLabel mono axis"); 
        });
   ```

   Of course, you could combine those two translation statements, as:

   ```
       .attr("transform", function(d, i) { 
             return "translate(" + ( (i + 0.5) * gridSize) + ",-6)"
                     + "rotate(-90)")
   ```
2. Alternately, you can specify a center of rotation in the rotate statement, by including the x and y values of the point you want it to rotate around:

   ```
   var timeLabels = svg.selectAll(".timeLabel")
     .data(times)
     .enter().append("text")
       .text(function(d) { return d; })
       .attr("x", function(d, i) { return i * gridSize; })
       .attr("y", 0)
       .attr("transform", function(d, i) { 
             return "translate(" + gridSize / 2 + ", -6)" +
                    "rotate(-90 "+ ((i + 0.5) * gridSize) + " " + (-6) +")";
        } )
       .style("text-anchor", "end")
       .attr("class", function(d, i) { return ((i >= 8 && i <= 16) ? 
                                  "timeLabel mono axis axis-worktime" : 
                                  "timeLabel mono axis"); 
        });
   ```

   As you can see, this version is rather repetitive, as we have to calculate the position of the label twice -- once to position it, and once to set the center of rotation.  You can see why most examples (and the d3 axis functions) position the labels with translations, so they can just be rotated in place.

Comment: Thank you very much for the brief explanation. Thanks a lot :).

Comment: I need one more help. You could see the first box in the second row is missing. Actually it's getting overlapped on the first box of the first row. The `y` value of the first box of second row is as the same as first box of the first row. Can you help me fix it?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have any insights just from looking at the picture.  If you can't figure it out after going through your code carefully for typos, post another question with your code for positioning the squares.  A working example would be even better.

Answer (score -3):

Try this code:

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manojmcet/g47hN/)**:

```
 svg.append("g") // Add the X Axis
.attr("class", "x axis")
.attr("id", "x")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (h) + ")")
    .call(xAxis)
    .selectAll("text")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .attr("dx", "-.8em")
    .attr("dy", ".15em")
    .attr("transform", function (d) {
    return "rotate(-90)";
});
```

Comment: Function what you've written doesn't help me in my case.

Comment: The fiddle doesn't even work. The text is not rotated.